# FormData is not defined in React Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am writing a unit testing code for the React project. I am trying to test one function

```
//function aa
export const login = (values) => async => (dispatch) => {
  let bodyFormData = new FormData();

  bodyFormData.append('username', values.login);
  bodyFormData.append('password', values.password);
  return await axios({
   method: 'post',
   url: url,
   data: bodyFormData
  }
}

//aa test
it("Login Action", async () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    store.clearActions();
  });
  const values = {
    login: "aaaaa",
    password: "bbbbb"
  };
  const expectedResult = { type: "LOGIN_PASS" };

  const result = await store.dispatch(login(values));
  expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
});
```

In the browser, this works ok. but when testing I get below error

**ReferenceError: FormData is not defined**

I tried to use this module but no luck...
https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data

I do not want to just test axios, I need to test full function.

Comment: I don't see your code creating a `const FormData = require("form-data")` though? Because it kind of needs that if you want to use that browser-only bit of data structure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to mock `FormData` within your unit test, as the `FormData` web API is not  available in the node.js/jsdom environment.

```
function FormDataMock() {
  this.append = jest.fn();
}

global.FormData = FormDataMock
```

If you wish to mock other methods within the `FormData` global:

```
const entries = jest.fn()
global.FormData = () => ({ entries })
```

Comment: Do I need to add const FormData = require("form-data") with your code?

Comment: @Lee I think `const formData = new FormData()` is sufficient, but if its not, you can try the statement you used?

Comment: Thanks, but I faced new problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743632/axios-post-with-react-jest

Comment: ```new window.FormData()``` will do

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing this issue and it turned out that `testEnvironment` (inside `jest.config.js`) was set to `'node'`. Changing it to `'jsdom'` resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mock the FormData for same, simply add below lines in top of test file.

```
// @ts-ignore
global.FormData = require('react-native/Libraries/Network/FormData');
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted "global.FormData" mock answer didn't work for me. Typescript doesn't like it and I'm not completely sure of the proper way to handle that single use case. What *did* work was mocking it in the jest configuration file:

```
// jest.config.js

const { defaults } = require('jest-config');

module.exports = {
  ...,
  setupFiles: [
    'path/to/jest.setup.js',
  ],
}
```

And then in the referenced setup file...

```
// jest.setup.js

Object.defineProperty(window, 'FormData', {
  writable: true,
  value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    append: jest.fn()
  }))
})
```