# Axios post with react + jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, axios

when development + production, server-side(PHP) gets below array

```
array(2) {
  ["username"]=>
  string(8) "abc12345"
  ["password"]=>
  string(6) "1111"
}
```

but if I test with jest

```
 ["----------------------------366071262138387187326757
    Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name"]=>
      string(193) ""username"

    abc12345
    ----------------------------366071262138387187326757
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

    1111
    ----------------------------366071262138387187326757--
    "
    }
```

So I cannot get value using $_POST["username"]

below is axios setting

```
const FormData = require("form-data")

let bodyFormData = new FormData();

bodyFormData.append('username', values.login);
bodyFormData.append('password', values.password);

return await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: url,
    data: bodyFormData,
    config: { 
      headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      } 
    }
})
```

How do I send data with the same format as dev + prod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `FormData` for a simple form POST. It requires.the use of the `multipart/form-data` Content-Type which is fairly complex, and typically used when uploading files rather than typical form data.

I presume your server would be expecting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so try:

```
const qs = require('querystring');
...
const data = qs.stringify({
  username: values.login,
  password: values.password
});
return await axios.post(url, data, {
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  } 
})
```

Comment: My project already has so many axios with formdata. anyway with using formdata?

Comment: @Lee it's not about Axios here, it's about how your server is processing the data. You would need to change your server to expect & parse a `multipart/form-data` request, which as my answer states would be far more complex than using something like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, or even `application/json`.