Jest - passing FormEvent to function to be tested
I have the following method that I'd like to test with Jest (well, more precisely with vitest):
export const handleSave = async (
    dispatch: React.Dispatch<DeveloperAction>, 
    e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>, 
    handleClose: () => void, 
    setErrorMessage: (errorMessage: string) => void) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    const formData: FormData = new FormData(e.currentTarget)
    const developer: DeveloperType = toDeveloperType(formData)

    try {
        const resp: AxiosResponse = await axios({
            method: 'PUT', 
            url: `${endpointBackEnd}/developers/${formData.get('id')}`, 
            data: developer
        }); 
        dispatch({ 
            type: DEVELOPER_ACTION_TYPES.EDIT, 
            payload: resp.data 
        })       
        handleClose();
    } catch (err) {
        handleError(err, setErrorMessage)
    }
}

My question is about how to pass a FormEvent that the function can use to create a FormData which later is used to extract information from?
Should I pass a mocked FormEvent (how can I do that)? Or create an instance of FormEvent (the question is the same, how to do that please?)
Thank you for the help!

There are three points you need to think about for the FormEvent:

e.preventDefault(); - use a jest function to mock this
e.currentTarget - make sure the correct HTMLFormElement class is passed to the event
formData.get('id') - build your form using .name and .value of input fields in the virtual form.

Option 1. Use JSDom to mock out the FormData
import { FormEvent } from 'react';
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

const dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html>'), doc = dom.window.document;
const formElement = doc.createElement('form');
const formField = doc.createElement('input');
formElement.append(formField);

formField.value = 'hi';
formField.name = 'id';

const form: Partial<FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>> = {
  currentTarget: formElement,
  preventDefault: () => jest.fn(),
};
const formData: FormData = new FormData(form.currentTarget);

const e = {
  preventDefault: jest.fn(),
  currentTarget: formElement
} as FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>;
  

Option 2. Testing in isolation of the DOM
This answer provides the method for mocking out the FormData class in jest:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59726560/4529555

Yes! Option 1 works like a charm! Thank you very much!
